# How to use Oracle Entity Framework with no config file

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odp.net

Is it possible to create a code-first Entity Framework model that connects to an existing database using ODP.Net without having any settings in the app.config file?

I have tried many different things.

Currently I am setting DbConfiguration:

```
    sealed class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public static readonly DbConfiguration Instance = new EntityFrameworkConfiguration();

        EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new OracleConnectionFactory());
            this.SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
        }
    }

    DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(EntityFrameworkConfiguration.Instance);
```

I am passing an `OracleConnection` directly into the EF context.

However, I either have problems with the SQL being generated in SQL Server format (using double-quotes around table aliases), or I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

Has anyone any experience of getting this to work without polluting app.config with crud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uff. Found the problem.

Because I was registering column mapping using lower case the query didn't work. The column and table names must be in upper-case.

How silly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. To complete the switch from machine.config/app.config to code-based configuration, I had to also include a call to `SetProviderFactory()`.

```
public sealed class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public static readonly DbConfiguration Instance = new EntityFrameworkConfiguration();

    public EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new OracleConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", new OracleClientFactory());
    }
}
```

I also called `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(EntityFrameworkConfiguration.Instance);` in the startup of my application because I had DbContext's in multiple assemblies that all needed to share this configuration.

On a side note, I have also found this to be effective in allowing your application to work around the `ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'DbProviderFactories' section can only appear once per config file` for cases where you may not have access to repair the user's machine.config.